# web development on Mac

Tags: asp.net, macos, web

I'm from a .NET background and have built a few asp.net applications using Visual Studio.  I haven't done any coding in a few years though.

I have recently purchased a Mac and would like to get back into web development.

I cant seem to find any resources on the best way to create a project that would comprise of:

1. Web forms
2. Web Services
3. Database

What is the way to setup a web server, application server,database server and what are the tools I should use to develop/deploy?

Whenever I google this I get really obscure results like I am the first person to have ever asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

[MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) will give you a simple Mac Apache MySQL PHP stack. But it’s hard to know what to suggest when you don’t say what technology you want to use to develop for the web on your Mac.

Comment: Well I dont know what technologies are available and "mainstream". I would be happy to go down the PHP path.I didnt think I could write services with PHP..